# How can I write a VB script to search for a file and show its version information?

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I'm trying to create a vb script that allows me to search directories and sub-directories for a file, get its location and version information.

The file could be anything such as a .dll or .exe.

In command prompt I was able to use : dir /s /b c:(filename) to search for the file.

How can I combine the two requirements?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: tag "shell" was removed. read tag-wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example to enumerate a folder and its subfolders and get the file version from exe files, mind you this is something other than the product version.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\windows")
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

enum_files colFiles
For Each objFolder in objFolder.Subfolders
  Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
  enum_files colFiles
Next

Sub enum_files (colFiles)
  For Each objFile in colFiles
    if lCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "exe" then
      Wscript.Echo objFile.path & " " & objFSO.GetFileVersion(objFile.path)
    end if
  Next
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really close. Is there a way to state only drive c:\ and search for lets say calc.exe and pull its version?

Comment: of course, you have all the elements here, for a start calc.exe resides under c:\windows (line 2) so the only thing you have to do is check in enum_files is if objFile.name = "calc.exe"
But in a folder like c:\windows there are security issues so you will need errortrapping